# How do I reset a variable at the start of each day?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a variable that keeps track of user statistic I want to reset at the beginning of each day. How can I do that?
Since the application is not allowed to run in the background, it seems I will have to do the check every time the application is active but I don't know how to reset the variable I have only once. This is the function I wanted to use:

```
    let beginingOfDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
    func resetCurrentTime(){

    // Date comparision to compare current date and begining of the day.
    let dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(beginingOfDay)

    if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending || dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
        // Current date is greater or equal to end date.
        currentTime = 0 //reset the time tracker
    }
}
```

I wanted to use this function to check when the application is launched but the problem is that the application could be launched many time a day. How I can reset my variable only once at the beginning of a day if the user is using the application or when the application becomes active or is launched for the first time that day? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store in the user defaults this value.

So the flow is the following:

1. When the app is launched or became active you check whether the value of the variable in the user defaults is the same as the current day (e.g. 25/07/2016), then do nothing.
2. If the value is different, then you update the value in the user defaults with the current day.

If the app is running and the date is changed, you can update the value of your variable by subscribing to this notification: 
`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`

Comment: I didn't know that notification existed. When is it posted by the system?

Comment: From the docs: Posted when there is a significant change in time, for example, change to a new day (midnight), carrier time update, and change to or from daylight savings time.

Comment: what does carrier update means and how will affect my timing? Is there a more restricted notification that only fire at midnight in absolute term?

Comment: it doesn't matter if the reason for the notification was not the midnight change. In any case you will run your code and if the date is the same, it will not update the value in the user defaults.

Comment: Hello, do you mind giving a code example for this process?