# How to make the value of a variable reset every day

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, time

I want to make an exercise app to help users track their daily exercise and I have a variable `exerciseTime` that I want to reset every day. Is there any way to do that?

The variable is stored in app storage `@AppStorage("exerciseTime") var exerciseTime = 0.0` and connected to a timer.

```
            Text("Time: \(format(seconds: timerStruct.countdownTimer))")
                .padding()
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if timerStruct.countdownTimer > 0 && timerStruct.timerRunning == true {
                        timerStruct.countdownTimer -= 1
                        exerciseTime += 1.0
                    } else {
                        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
                        if timerStruct.countdownTimer <= 0, timerStruct.timerRunning == false {
                            timerStruct.isAlertpresented = true
                            reset()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a variable at the start of each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576229/how-do-i-reset-a-variable-at-the-start-of-each-day)

Comment: no not really, I tried it and I keep on getting errors and I think I need a simpler solution that I can understand

Comment: Are you saying that the user automatically starts exercising as soon as they start your app? Shouldn’t you have some kind of action (button) for starting and stopping the exercise? Also from your code it looks like you update UserDefaults every second which is certainly not how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: no there is a button to start and stop the exercise and the variable is updated every second because I want to store how many seconds the user has exercised for so I just want this value to reset every day.

Answer (score 1):

This function checks if the current date is in the same day as a saved date in `UserDefaults`

Just call it always when the app becomes active

```
func isNewDay() -> Bool {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let now = Date.now
    if let savedDate = defaults.object(forKey: "currentDate") as? Date,
       Calendar.current.compare(savedDate, to: now, toGranularity: .day) == .orderedSame {
        return false
    }
    defaults.set(now, forKey: "currentDate")
    return true
}
```